# Describe the Riemann surface for $w=z^2-1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

**Question:**

> Describe the Riemann surface for $w=z^2-1$.

My thoughts so far: the Riemann surface needs two cuts emanating from the origin across the real line since it maps every input to one point above the real line and one point below. This means we would need two "sheets" to make the mapping one-to-one.

Comment: Can you unaccept my answer so I can delete it? It's incorrect.

Comment: I have moved my incorrect answer to it's proper place, so I would appreciate it if someone could please delete it. Thanks! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364172/describe-the-riemann-surface-for-w2-z2-1/1364174#1364174

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what should be the correct answer. We have $z=\sqrt{w+1}$ with a single branch point at $-1$. So, following the construction of the surface for $z^2=w$, we cut two copies of the plane along the real axis from $-1$ to infinity and glue them together along the slit.

The compactification should have genus $0$ (since all irreducible conics are topologically equivalent to the Riemann sphere).

Comment: Hi @potato, your original answer, assuming +/- i were the correct branch points, is still awesome, and I hope it doesn't get removed by the original poster :-)  The idea of choosing overlapping branch cuts is really cool (and at first, very tricky to grasp).  Can I ask you just one follow-up question:  obviously all the points on a branch cut are, by definition, branch points.  But how do you find the branch points of a function, just by looking at it?  Is it always the zeroes of the function f(z) in the compostion, log(f(z)), which in this case f(z) is w+1?  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames So here we have two sheets of the surface. The branch points are where the map fails to be 2 to 1. So here, every value of $w$ gives $2$ different answers, except when $w=-1$. I think your heuristic works.

Comment: @LebronJames Another way to think about this is that you're trying to get a single-valued version of $\sqrt{w+1}$, and to do that you need to "kill the monodromy." Consider it this way. Why can't we define a single valued version of $\sqrt{w+1}$ on all of $\mathbb C$? Because when we wrap around the point $-1$, the argument changes by $\pi i$. So we add the slit from $0$ to $\infty$ to prevent that problem. Once the function can't wrap around $0$ and change its argument like that, we get a single valued function. But this gives two different "sheets," which we must glue together.

Comment: @LebronJames Refer to pages 34-36 here for some pictures, especially the nice picture on page 36: http://www.math.wustl.edu/~matkerr/AGbook.pdf

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much for your help and for the reference, @potato!!  Have a great night!  :-)

Comment: @Potato As requested, I have unaccepted your original and accepted this one instead! Thanks, Potato.