# Describe the Riemann surface for $w^2=z^2-1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Describe the Riemann surface for $w^2=z^2-1$.

[Editorial note: I'm posting this to save an answer on [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058658/describe-the-riemann-surface-for-w-z2-1), which actually answers this question instead.]

Answer (score 2):

Take two copies of $\mathbb C$. Cut each from $-i$ to $i$. Then you have a well-defined choice of $z$ on each, and you can glue them together along the cuts to get the complete Riemann surface.

Here's why this works. You want to choose a branch of $z=\sqrt{w^2+1}$. The branch points here are $\pm i$. Recall that at a branch cut, the argument "jumps" by $i\pi$. So make two cuts, one for each branch point, going down the imaginary axis. It looks like you must cut out everything from i downwards. But below $−i$, you have two "jumps" of $i\pi$, or a single jump of $2i\pi$, which doesn't change anything, so you can continue the function across that infinite ray. So only $i$ to $−i$ needs to be cut out.

This method also shows that the compactification has genus $0$ (repeat the above using Riemann spheres).

Comment: It might be worthwhile to add that the choice of branch cuts is not unique. We could have taken one cut to be a curved contour that originated at $z=i$ and extends to the point at infinity and take the second branch cut to be a more conventional one - beginning at $z=-i$ and extending on the negative imaginary axis.  There are applications for which choosing a non-linear contour facilitates analysis.  See [this text](http://www.amazon.com/Field-Theory-Guided-Robert-Collin/dp/0879422378) , Chapter 11, pp. 727-735 in which we see branch cuts that are hyperbolas.  Interesting application.